# Regular expression with Javascript to check Japanese input

Tags: javascript, regex, visual-studio

today I met a problem that I could not find out why. Until yesterday I could check Japanese input, for example Hiragana, using regular expression pattern like this `/[\p{Hiragana}]{1,5}/` with javascript on chrome/firefox browsers.

But today, I could not and I had to change the pattern to this `/[あ-ん]{1,5}/` and it could work again. There is same problem with Katakana and Kanji input. It is not problem of chrome or firefox setting.

I do not thing that by accident I made any changes in my local japanese windows10 input/encode setting. I checked everything on my browsers/PC/my code and I could not find out why.

If you have the same problem please kindly tell me why. Many thanks in advance. I am working with visual studio 2015 community version. If you need more information, please let me know.

---

*Code from comments:*

cshtml:

```
<form name="myForm" method="post">
    <input id="alert" type="text" name="name" value="" />
    <input type="submit" formaction="~/select" onclick="return validateForm()" value="次へ" />
<form>
```

JavaScript:

```
function validateForm() {
    var name = document.forms["myForm"]["name"].value;
    var pattern = /([\u4e00-\u9faf]+|[あ-ん]+|[ア-ン]+)+((\s|　)([\u4e00-\u9faf]+|[‌​あ-ん]+|[ア-ン]+)+)+/i;
    if (pattern.test(name) == false) {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
};
```

Comment: It's odd since javascript doesn't support unicode scripts.

Comment: It looks like you're using XRegExp or another library/plugin that converts unicode regexes. That library and/or the Unicode add-in needed for this regex is probably not loaded. In any case some more code that shows how exactly you construct the regexes would be helpful.

Comment: Thank you all. I'll check XRegExp. I'm building a web application using asp.net 4.5 mvc. Below is my code.
cshtml
<form name="myForm" method="post">
<input id="alert" type="text" name="name" value="@Request.Form["name"]" />
<input type="submit" formaction="~/select" onclick="return validateForm()" value="次へ" />
<form>
Js
function validateForm() {
var name = document.forms["myForm"]["name"].value;
var pattern = /([\u4e00-\u9faf]+|[あ-ん]+|[ア-ン]+)+((\s|　)([\u4e00-\u9faf]+|[あ-ん]+|[ア-ン]+)+)+/i;
    if (pattern.test(name) == false) {
        // do st
        return false;
    }
};

Comment: The pattern I provided above comment worked well in javascript. However the pattern below did not work and I do not know why.

var pattern = /([\p{Han}]+|[\p{Hiragana}]+|[\p{Katakana}]+)+((\s|　)([\p{Han}]+|[\p{Hiragana}]+|[\p{Katakana}]+)+)+/i;

Comment: @PhuongPhan I've added your code to your question. You shouldn't post your code in the comments. Simply edit your question.

Comment: Thank you very much ssc-hrep3.

Comment: You mentioned ASP.NET. You must have had `runat="server"` and used .NET regex engine to parse your patterns and `[\p{Hiragana}]{1,5}` is a valid pattern for .NET regex engine. If you disabled the server-side validation, the Unicode category class cannot be handled by JavaScript regex engine.

Comment: @Victor Stribizew Sorry, you might true about asp.net, but i am using asp.net mvc. I tested with both client and server side validations and the above problem still existed. I myself think that it is problem of asp.net mvc, a kind of bug i think. With my experience with asp.net mvc now, razor failed to pass data via get/post method via both parameter pass and data binding pass. And more surprised, asp.net mvc also does not work well with MySQL syntax.